# String,Long cannot be mapped to an object in Map.Entry<String,Long>

Tags: java

I want to create a contact list in java. First i created HashMap. String for name and long for number. Then i inserted HashMap object into a list.Now i have to display the contacts that are added.But i am getting error that Map.Entry cannot be mapped to an object

```
for(HashMap hashmapobject:listobj){
for(Map.Entry<String,Long> e:hashmapobject.entrySet())
//to get values in hashmap
}
```

Comment: How did you define the HashMap and List? Your posted code is not enough to see where you're having a problem.

Comment: Please add more code to improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap hashmapobject:listobj
```

It equals: HashMap, so entrySet() returns Entry < Object, Object >, not < String, Long >.
You should use HashMap < String, Long > hashmapobject:listobj();

Or you can write this way:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : e:hashmapobject.entrySet()) {
    final String key = (String)entry.getKey();
    final Long val = (Long) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
   Long l = map.get(key);
}
```

try using this approach to iterate over the hashmap. by using the above loop you are getting the key as a string and by providing the key you can get the object from your map.

Answer (score 0):

For looping a hash map with `Map.Entry:`

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "Jan");
map.put("2", "Feb");
map.put("3", "Mar");

//loop a Map
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

You should give generics for the hash map inorder to loop using `Map.Entry`.